# Laravel - reCAPTCHA resubmit

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I have integrated reCAPTCHA using Guzzle Client, as follows:

```
Validator::extend('recaptcha', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->post(env('RECAPTCHA_VERFIY_URL'), [
        'form_params' => [
            'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'),
            'response' => $value
        ]
    ]);

    $body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());

    return $body->success;
});
```

Then in my validation rules I have:

`'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'`

This works fine, however the problem I am having is if the reCAPTCHA has been ticked and verified and I try to resubmit the form (for example if the initial submit contained errors), I receive a "false" response back. The user is unable to retick the box.

How can I handle the situation where I need to resubmit the reCAPTCHA? I am submitting and validating the forms via AJAX.

Comment: You need to run `grecaptcha.reset();` in your JS to generate a new token after the form has failed.

Comment: Thanks @TheFallen. How can I check if reCAPTCHA has been loaded before I run that? It doesn't appear on every form and I use a common validation function for all my forms.

Comment: If your form has been successfully submitted with ajax then recaptcha is 100% loaded, there is no need to check. After your ajax callback is activated you can run this code to reload the recaptcha token.